# Add a global error in Spring MVC from a non-controller location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Somewhere in my Spring MVC app I need to add a global error. I no longer have access to any BindingResult, I only have my Request. My error is not the result of any binding issues, it's a global condition. Then I need to attach my new Errors object to the "errors" Req. attribute, so the JSP can display it.

But how to do this? I can't do

```
Errors errors = new Errors();
errors.reject(....);
request.setAttribute("errors", errors);
```

because Errors is an interface. The implementations all have to do with 'Binding',like `BindException, AbstractBindingResult, MapBindingResult`, etc. These all have nothing to do with my case, I don't have a binding field error, it's a general error msg.

Any tips?

Comment: The normal way to signal an error is to throw an exception. You can then catch the exception in the controller, and add the global error there.

Comment: Thank you but once I can add an error, I need to construct an ObjectError or FieldError? Both of these require an 'Object' which I don't have. Do I pass in NULL? The superclass which doesn't have an object, DefaultMessageResolveable, can't be added with bindingResult.addError().

Comment: Looks like NULL doesn't work for ObjectError but "" (empty string) does. Thanks I'll write up an answer based on your tip.

Answer (score 2):

Our resolution to this problem: The proper way to handle EXCEPTIONS (rather than VALIDATION errors) is to keep track of our own, custom Request Attribute that we display ourselves in our error area on the JSP.

BindingResult/Errors/etc. are all Binding-related, we can't hack it to handle general exception errors.

We just add a custom Request Attr. called "exceptions" and then our Error section checks for this additonal attribute list to display.

SpringMVC doesn't provide its own 'generic' Error collection.